# Keep style hover when a link is clicked

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep the hover style when a link in the side-bar is clicked.

I mean I click over one of the links, and after that, I want to click on another link , button or any place in the site out of the side-bar.

I want to preserve the hover style, but when I click in one of the links in the side-bar the style in the previous link selected gets removed.

```css
#menu > ul{list-style: none;padding: 0px;}
.col-md-3.temp {
    width: 28%;
}

#menu >ul >li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

 #tcolor{background-color: #d0cece;height: 93px;
    width: 20%;}
    #tcolor:hover
    {background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);}
  
#templatebtn {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    background-image: url(../images/Templates_off_ico.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 20%;
    height: 94px;
}

#templatebtn:hover,
#templatebtn:focus{
    background-image: url(../images/Templates_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}

#signaturebtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Signatures_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 0px;
}

#signaturebtn:hover, #signaturebtn:focus{
    background-image: url(../images/Signatures_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);  
}

#contactsbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Contacts_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
}

#contactsbtn:hover, #contactsbtn:focus{
    background-image: url(../images/Contacts_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
   
}

#clipsbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Clips_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center; 
}

#clipsbtn:hover, #clipsbtn:focus{
    background-image: url(../images/Clips_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}

#librariesbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Libraries_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center; 
}

#librariesbtn:hover, #librariesbtn:focus{
    background-image: url(../images/Libraries_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%); 
}

#usersbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Users_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;  
}

#usersbtn:hover, #usersbtn:focus {
    background-image: url(../images/Users_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%); 
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"> 
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li>
                    <div id="tcolor"><a href="#templates" id="templatebtn"></a></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <div id="tcolor"><a href="#signatures" id="signaturebtn"></a></div>  
                </li>
                <li>
                   <div id="tcolor"> <a href="#contacts" id="contactsbtn"></a></div>  
                </li>
                <li>
                   <div id="tcolor"> <a href="#clips" id="clipsbtn"></a></div> 
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div id="tcolor"> <a href="#libraries" id="librariesbtn"></a></div>  
                </li>
                <li>
                   <div id="tcolor"> <a href="#users" id="usersbtn"></a></div>  
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is using jQuery an option for you?

Comment: Could be,  but if is posible with css will be great!

Comment: @alsuelo Did the `:visited` selector work for you ?

Comment: @Onilol Not at all, because i cant remove the previous link :visited, could be the pseudo-class order?

Comment: @alsuelo would you mind taking some screenshots ?

Comment: @Onilol http://postimg.org/gallery/sw8u1cfg/ First image when nothing is clicked, second one when hover, third one when click, fourth one when other link is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give jQuery a try, here is the example how it would work out for you. First of all, I've replaced `#tcolor` with `.tcolor` , ID's has to be unique, if you want to style `> 1` elements with the same CSS rule, use classes. Same for your anchor links, you don't have to redefine each button style again and again, just unify all similarities inside a class targeted CSS rule and apply the differences by using an ID targeted CSS rule.

More about **[CSS class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)**

More about **[CSS ID selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)**

Take a look at the snippet below.

```js
   
$('.tcolor > a').click(function() {
  $('.tcolor').removeClass('hovered');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

```css
/* Added */

html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* */

#menu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
.col-md-3.temp {
  width: 28%;
}
#menu >ul >li {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
.tcolor {
  background-color: #d0cece;
  height: 93px;
  width: 20%;
}
.tcolor:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
/* Added */

.tcolor.hovered {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
.tcolor > a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
/* */

#templatebtn {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  background-image: url(../images/Templates_off_ico.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 20%;
  height: 94px;
}
#templatebtn:hover,
#templatebtn:focus {
  background-image: url(../images/Templates_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#signaturebtn {
  background-image: url(../images/Signatures_off_ico.png);
  height: 94px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
}
#signaturebtn:hover,
#signaturebtn:focus {
  background-image: url(../images/Signatures_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#contactsbtn {
  background-image: url(../images/Contacts_off_ico.png);
  height: 94px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
}
#contactsbtn:hover,
#contactsbtn:focus {
  background-image: url(../images/Contacts_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#clipsbtn {
  background-image: url(../images/Clips_off_ico.png);
  height: 94px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
}
#clipsbtn:hover,
#clipsbtn:focus {
  background-image: url(../images/Clips_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#librariesbtn {
  background-image: url(../images/Libraries_off_ico.png);
  height: 94px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
}
#librariesbtn:hover,
#librariesbtn:focus {
  background-image: url(../images/Libraries_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#usersbtn {
  background-image: url(../images/Users_off_ico.png);
  height: 94px;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  background-position: center;
}
#usersbtn:hover,
#usersbtn:focus {
  background-image: url(../images/Users_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
      <div class="tcolor"><a href="#templates" id="templatebtn">Link 1</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tcolor"><a href="#signatures" id="signaturebtn">Link 2</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tcolor"> <a href="#contacts" id="contactsbtn">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tcolor"> <a href="#clips" id="clipsbtn">Link 4</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tcolor"> <a href="#libraries" id="librariesbtn">Link 5</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tcolor"> <a href="#users" id="usersbtn">Link 6</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to point out that in valid HTML the id attribute is supposed to be unique on a page. Because of this, I recommend changing `id="tcolor"` to `class="tcolor"`. You can reference the class attribute in your css with a period (`.class`) instead of a number sign (`#id`). You may also have multiple class attribute values for a single element by separating their names with a space (`class="class1 class2"`).

Now on to your actual question:

I don't think what you want to do is possible without some JavaScript. The example below uses the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com). It is possible to do it without this library, but it is very common and makes so many cross browser things easier, that I recommend it.

With the below solution, I'm also getting the impression that you may want a sightly different style for `:hover` than the `.selected` so you can tell them apart, but that's a design choice.

```js
// This will run on page load
$(function(){
    // This binds a handler to the click event of any <li> 
    // in #menu (even if the <li> did not exist on page load, 
    // as long as #menu did)
    $('#menu').on('click', 'li',function(){
        // Add class="selected" to the <li> clicked on
        // and removes any class="selected" from the ones who weren't
        $(this).addClass('selected')
            .siblings()
            .removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```

```css
#menu > ul{list-style: none;padding: 0px;}
.col-md-3.temp {
    width: 28%;
}
#menu >ul >li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
.tcolor{background-color: #d0cece;height: 93px;
    width: 20%;}
    .tcolor:hover,
    #menu li.selected .tcolor
    {background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#templatebtn {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    background-image: url(../images/Templates_off_ico.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 20%;
    height: 94px;
}
#templatebtn:hover,
#templatebtn:focus,
#menu li.selected #templatebtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Templates_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#signaturebtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Signatures_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
   
    padding: 0px;
}
#signaturebtn:hover, #signaturebtn:focus,
#menu li.selected #signaturebtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Signatures_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);  
}
#contactsbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Contacts_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
}
#contactsbtn:hover, #contactsbtn:focus,
#menu li.selected #contactsbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Contacts_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#clipsbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Clips_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
}
#clipsbtn:hover, #clipsbtn:focus,
#menu li.selected #clipsbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Clips_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#librariesbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Libraries_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
}
#librariesbtn:hover, #librariesbtn:focus,
#menu li.selected #librariesbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Libraries_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
#usersbtn{
    background-image: url(../images/Users_off_ico.png);
    height: 94px;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
}
#usersbtn:hover, #usersbtn:focus,
#menu li.selected #usersbtn {
    background-image: url(../images/Users_on_ico.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #16bdcf 10%, #3f3736 10%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <div class="tcolor">
                <a href="#templates" id="templatebtn"></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="tcolor">
                <a href="#signatures" id="signaturebtn"></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="tcolor">
                <a href="#contacts" id="contactsbtn"></a>
            </div> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="tcolor">
                <a href="#clips" id="clipsbtn"></a>
            </div> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="tcolor">
                <a href="#libraries" id="librariesbtn"></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="tcolor">
                <a href="#users" id="usersbtn"></a>
            </div>  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I am noticing that your `<li>` tags have a width of 100%, so clicking anywhere to the right of them fires the event handler, but this could be fixed by positioning your `<ul>` to only take up the space desired.

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit the `:visited` property.

The `:visited` CSS pseudo-class lets you select only links that have been visited. This style may be overridden by any other link-related pseudo-classes, that is `:link`, `:hover`, and `:active`, appearing in subsequent rules. In order to style appropriately links, you need to put the `:visited` rule after the `:link` rule but before the other ones, defined in the LVHA-order: `:link` — `:visited` — `:hover` — `:active`.

Source :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avisited

Comment: I quote: "But when i click in one of the links in the side bar remove the style in the previous link selected in the sidebar." This means your answer is invalid.